# Any chance of a hide closed questions option?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add the ability to filter [Closed] questions out of my results.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/please-add-the-ability-to-filter-closed-questions-out-of-my-results)

I cloned myself by accident!

**Dupe of:** [Please add the ability to filter [Closed] questions out of my results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7913)

I understand the desire to keep closed questions around as information to future users searching for the same thing, but during busy times e.g. 9-5 EST there can be many of them cluttering up the first 5-10 pages of questions on StackOverflow.

I'd love an option to hide closed questions when I am just browsing the questions pages, 1,2,3,4,5... etc. Since I can't really do anything with them (answer, assist, clarify, etc.). and they mostly fall into the "read the FAQ before posting category"

Of course if a user searches for something like "jQuery form", by all means keep the closed questions visible.

Alternatively, I'd be happy if the closed questions were "dimmed" similar to the questions that I tag "ignore".

Comment: You've posted your own dupe.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7913

Comment: "The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results." - Albert Einstein.

Comment: Ack! @random - don't I feel like a fool now! yes, it does appear to be a dupe.  Oddly enough though, when I searched meta to see if this question had been asked, and when I started asking the question, I didn't find any dupes.  I wonder if "my" questions are filtered out when asking?