# Avoiding "closed" questions in a search

Tags: support, search, closed-questions

When searching for questions, is there a way to avoid all those marked `[closed]` at the end? I know how to find questions with "truly" 0 answers (`answers:0`).

Skipping closed questions would be nice in search results.

Comment: Damn - didn't think to check if it was a dupe.

Comment: and I couldn't find the dupe either :-|

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7913

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `closed:0` to your search.

For example, to search for all the truly unanswered questions I use:

`http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed:0%20hasaccepted:0%20answers:0%20[c%23]&tab=newest`

Answer (score -1):

Closed as duplicate are useful in searches as they provide different keywords to search for