# How to avoid closed questions in listing

Tags: support, search, question-lists

I found several accepted answers for this question, but still have difficulties:

1. [Please add the ability to filter [Closed] questions out of my results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/please-add-the-ability-to-filter-closed-questions-out-of-my-results)
2. [Avoiding "closed" questions in a search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25496/avoiding-closed-questions-in-a-search/25497#25497)

From both answers I don't understand, what should I do to avoid closed questions by default, so I won't need to insert closed:0 every time manually.

Usually I work with the site like this:

1. Open `http://stackoverflow.com`
2. click php tag, and this page is opened: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Is is possible to enter in some filter in my profile, that I don't want to get closed questions in any listing by default?

### 2-nd subquestion

Is it possible to filter the questions, having low score: <= -4 for example? I don't want to see them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, both of those are supported:

- [No closed questions in the PHP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bphp%5d%20closed%3a0)
- [Questions scoring more than -4 in the PHP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bphp%5d%20score%3a-3)
- [Questions that aren't closed and score more than -4 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bphp%5d%20score%3a-3%20closed%3a0)

Pick a filter that works for you, and bookmark it. Enjoy!

For more on powerful search operators with which to impress your friends and frighten your enemies, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Maybe, in the future, it would be possible to setup these filters in the profile, so they are applied by default.

Comment: To frighten your enemies, I would recommend entering into a [different realm altogether](http://data.stackexchange.com/) where only the laws of SQL apply.