# Is there a way to exclude Closed questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags, closed-questions, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add the ability to filter [Closed] questions out of my results.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/please-add-the-ability-to-filter-closed-questions-out-of-my-results)

Currently I can filter topics that don't interest me. I'd love to see some kind of automatic tag of [Closed] added to closed questions so that I could exclude closed questions. Is there a way to do that already that I just missed?

Clarification: I don't mean when searching, I mean when looking at the main page, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions - I don't know (or use) Java, for example so I've got that excluded. I'd like to exclude *all* closed questions - not necessarily from searches I do, but just from the default display.

Clarification #2: On Stackoverlow.com, at least there is a [closed] tag but only 6 questions have it. If closed questions got it added automatically (and removed upon reopen) that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You did [just miss it](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Jimmy in the `closed:0` parameter in your search input and you're crowing out the closed questions:

> [closed:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed:0)

And if you're in the mood of scoping the scene for closed doors:

> [closed:1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed:1)

There is no real difference between viewing the site on the questions page over the search results. You just swap out the Hot and Featured tabs for Relevance. You still see your interesting and ignored tags taking effect.

If you have a tag, in your case **[[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)]**, on your ignored+hidden then it will also be hidden/ignored on your search results.

Comment: I thought closed questions were excluded from the search by default.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the confusion though - I wasn't talking about searching for questions.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could, I wouldn't recommend this. Just because it's closed doesn't mean it should be closed (hence the reopen option). If we all ignored closed questions, then valid questions that were wrongly closed would get no attention.

Comment: Closed questions in searches are helpful when they're dupes or worded differently but still on point.

Comment: I'm not sure all of us (based on our rep level) have the option to reopen questions. Perhaps if I could, I'd feel differently.

Comment: (Now that my comments are working again) @Mark - That's true. I can understand that since you have no say in the closing/reopening you don't really care about closed questions. I actually rather like your clarification #2 idea (though I won't be ignoring any `[closed]` tags I see).