# searching 'closed:0' by activity shows closed questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, closed-questions

This [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/please-add-the-ability-to-filter-closed-questions-out-of-my-results/25501#25501) suggests searching for `closed:0` to filter out closed questions from the start page. At least on programmers.SE, this does not seem to work as expected:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=closed%3a0

The above query contains the question 'What is the mysql function that combine dates? [closed]'.

Is this a bug or am I failing to use the feature correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99559/what-is-the-mysql-function-that-combine-dates) was only closed 32 minutes ago - so about 13 minutes before you asked this meta question - and if you search again you (hopefully) should find it is no longer in the search results.

I believe that you just happened to hit a cached result. There's always a chance that a cached result is no longer valid (as it was in this case), but that is usually rectified relatively quickly.

Comment: Indeed, the question vanished from the search results.

Answer (score 1):

We now index posts much more rapidly than before as part of [recent search changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange).  Results not matching the criteria will typically disappear within a minute on Stack Overflow, within 5 minutes on all other main sites, and within 10 minutes on all child metas.